# hide background webpage vertical scrollbar using jquery or javascript while load of popup page

Tags: javascript, jquery

By clicking `<a>click me</a>` tag, the popup windows will get load. At the time background page vertical scroll bar is on visible state. How can i hide while my popup load and visible when it close.

I used below script only:

```
if($("#myModal").is(':visible')){  // here 'myModal' is div of popup.
   $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");  // here 'html' is a background page
   }
   else
  {
   $("html").css("overflow", "visible");
  }
```

Hide state is working properly, but visible state not working when i close the popup window.

Please give me a correct solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the way you implement your modal... If for example you are using the [jQuery UI 
Dialog Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) you would do something like:

```
$("a.mylink").dialog({
    open: function() {
        $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
    },
    close: function() {
        $("html").css("overflow", "visible");
    }
});
```

Comment: here '.mylink' means what?

Comment: .mylink - or whatever you like - is just a class in your link which on click will open the modal.

Comment: nothing happened. i used "id of <a id='shide'> (i.e) $("shide")" instead of $("a.mylink"). is it correct?

Comment: You need $('#shide'). Also for my example  to work you need to include the jQuery UI library...<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> AFTER the jQuery.